# How to add/draw data in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I need to create a map of risk of PM 2.5 exposure by populations that have asthma. I need to create an additive model that quantifies areas with high and somewhat high concentration of PM 2.5 as well as areas with high and somewhat high areas of asthma rates. I am given a tabular dataset of asthma rates, PM 2.5 point dataset derived using land use regression from EPA monitors, a vector dataset made of up zip codes, and a boundary file.

How do I go about doing this?

I have never done a lab without instructions and I do not know how to begin.

It is arcgis 10.2 and I have not drawn the data.

Answer (score 1):

Various options for drawing data in ArcMap are described in an ArcGIS 10.2 Help page entitled [Adding layers to a map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Adding_layers_to_a_map/00660000000t000000/).  I think you should review that to see if it enables you to draw any/all of your datasets.

I think the best way to draw data is to drag and drop it from the Catalog window into your map but there are several methods described so if one does not suit you then try another of them.

If there are any particular datasets that you cannot draw using the above then you will be in a position to research/ask about the particular issue that you then face.

Until you can see all of your data sets in ArcMap either as layers (or tables), I think completing the assignment will not be possible.

Comment: I was able to draw the data. I see all my layers and the asthma table.

Comment: So that should answer your question about where to begin and give you the basis for your final map.  The other thing you said you need to create is an "additive model" so I recommend that you review whatever lectures/notes you have on that to see whether you can take the next steps from there.  If not, then research the web/here to see what other help may be available, and if you are still stuck then you should be in a position to ask a new question using the advice offered in [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question).

Comment: Please be aware that GIS SE is not here to do labs/homework/assignments for people and as per a [Meta discussion](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/how-to-treat-a-please-do-my-homework-for-me-question) our community will expect to see research effort from you at each step you ask for help on.